# Get data from database with where clause using API

Tags: api

I have a table named SerialNumbers containing some columns in it.

I want to get the data with SNum based on scanned value which has been listed in an Array.

Below is my code:

```
public class SNController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage AllSN()
    {
        using (SNDBContext dbContext = new SNDBContext())
        {

            string[] SNum = { "01070A2", "01070A3", "01070A4" };
            var SerialNum = dbContext.SNumbers.Where(x => x.SN == "01070A2")
                                  .Select(p => new { p.Name, p.Status})
                                  .ToList();
            
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, SerialNum );
        }
    }
```

When I try to hardcoded this part `var SerialNum = dbContext.SNumbers.Where(x => x.SN == "01070A2")`, its working.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Could you please add the problematic code instead of working one?

Answer (score 0):

Use Contains method in Where clause.

```
var SerialNum = dbContext.SNumbers.Where(x => SNum.Contains(x.SN))
                              .Select(p => new { p.Name, p.Status})
                              .ToList();
```

Comment: I've tried this method, but its showing all data instead of specific SerialNum